# How to share a React Native deep link and have it clickable?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

My React Native app supports [deep linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/) to a specific screen, so when a user clicks on an app link the phone will ask if the user wants to open the app, or at least that's what should happen.

The link looks something like this:

```
myapp://event/very-nice-event-1
```

But when sharing this link through an email, Messenger, Signal, etc. it's not clickable, just shown as regular text.

How do I go about sharing a deep link into an app?

Comment: Seems like custom protocol is not acceptable as links in applications. You need to use  [Android app links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) which start with `https://`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because many applications does not support all links because of safety reasons, in fact, only very few supports native deep links. For your deep links to work everywhere you would need to implement "Universal linking", which will be a http:// or https:// link. It's slightly more complicated but both IOS and Android has very well written documentation about the topic.